# Any way to preform One-way ANOVA with mean/sd/sample number in R?

Tags: r, anova

I have some datasets with means, standard deviations and sample numbers. I don't have the individual values. Is there any way to do an One-way ANOVA analysis using only means/sd/sample numbers?

I tried using the package "rpsychi" and while it did actually work, I don't quite understand how to test which groups are different from each other from the output.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of the data and the code you have tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.